# Zend Framework, PHPUnit and transactions

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, transactions, phpunit

i want to use PHP Unit inside a Zend Framework application. I need to make several database writing operations inside the tests.
I want to start an MySQL transaction in the setUpBeforeClass() method. That is possible, but if I try to rollback the transaction in the tearDownAfterClass() method he throws an exception with the message 'There is no active transaction'. And the test methods does the writing operations in the database.
But if i start the transaction in the test method itselfs. It works like I want.
I don't understand why it reacts like this. Knows anyone an explanation?

```
<?php

class ConferenceControllerTest
extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * A database connection.
     * @var Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
     */
    protected static $hostDb = null;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        static::$hostDb = Zend_Registry::get('db_host');
        static::$hostDb->beginTransaction();
        // The transaction for the Adapter is activated. But not inside the tests anymore.
    }


    public function testTest1()
    {
        // At this position teh transaction is not setted anymor? Why?
        static::$hostDb->beginTransaction();

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(5);';
        static::$hostDb->exec($sql);
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        try
        {
            static::$hostDb->rollBack();
        }
        catch(Exception $exception)
        {
            $message = $exception->getMessage();
            Zend_Debug::dump($message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be running into phpUnit's feature to backup statics and other globals between each unit test, see [the "globals" section of the Fixtures chapter of the manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.global-state)

The quick-hack fix would be to add this line, in the comments just above your class:
  * @backupStaticAttributes disabled

That still leaves you with the xUnit Patterns book would call a nasty smell. I'm assuming you have a few testXXX functions that you expect to run in a certain order, each depending on the result of the previous one? That requires using @depends on each function, and it is easy to get wrong.

The alternative approach is a single long unit test function, and put the DB code in setUp() and tearDown():

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->db = Zend_Registry::get('db_host');
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
}

public function tearDown()
{
    try
    {
        $this->db->rollBack();
    }
    catch(Exception $exception)
    {
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        Zend_Debug::dump($message);
    }


public function testTestVariousDBActions()
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES(5);';
    $this->db->exec($sql);

    //another DB action
    $this->assertEquals(...)

    //another DB action
    $this->assertEquals(...)

    //...
}
```

The advantage of this is that if any assert fails none of the subsequent ones will be attempted. But tearDown() will always be called so the database is restored.

The disadvantage could be you get a Very Long Function. Use refactoring to deal with this (e.g. if you really want each action and its test in its own function, refactor so it looks like that and have `testTestVariousDBActions()` call each of them in turn).